# Next page by clicking OK on alert box

Tags: php

First I have to show alert box then I have to transfer to another.But in my case it is not showing alert box and it is going to another page.

```
 echo "<script>alert('Your Record Sucessfully Inserted.Now Login');</script>";
 header('location:login.php');
```

Comment: if u want alert() than y u need `header()`

Comment: or use `alert()` in `login.php` file after redirection. or pass success status in url like `location:login.php?success=1` and show alert in `login.php` if `success = 1`

Comment: First I have registration form .First I will show alert box after clicking on ok it will go to another page.

Comment: we can apply if else condition here.like if(true) else.

Comment: @RahulPamnani you could use modals and make t look good. http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For achive this functionality you can do as below

```
echo "<script>if(confirm('Your Record Sucessfully Inserted. Now Login')){document.location.href='index.php'};</script>";
```

Comment: success message in confirm box, y?

Answer (score 1):

For this, you simply need to add some extra JavaScript after the alert.

```
echo "<script>alert('Your Record Sucessfully Inserted.Now Login');window.location.href = 'www.example.com';</script>";
```

Change `www.example.com` to whatever page you want to redirect to.

The `window.location.href = 'www.example.com';` is what redirects the user and won't run until the alert box is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is function that shows alert and then redirect you to another url:

```
 function myAlert($msg, $url){
    echo '<script language="javascript">alert("'.$msg.'");</script>';
    echo "<script>document.location = '$url'</script>";
}
myAlert("Your Record Sucessfully Inserted.Now Login", "login.php");
```